# Arranging images according to background in Java

Tags: java, image, user-interface, layout-manager

I'm trying to develop a Java program that does the following:

- uses a background picture of a network diagram of clients
- positions an image of a bandwidth graph to respective client
- refreshes the image of graph every 5 seconds which it fetches from another program that constantly produces snapshots of bandwidth

Now, I can set the background picture and I'm pretty confident that I will be able to refresh the images by using a timer. What I am trying to plan out is how I am going to position these images to the respective clients which is displayed in the background picture. I did some research and it appears that I have several options but I want to make sure I am choosing the right one before I run into problems further down the line.

It seems to me that using a GridBagLayout would be the choice for me, however I would like a second opinion for a more experienced population. If using a GridBagLayout is the correct choice, could you recommend any good tutorials that would help me understand this Layout Manager? Please keep in mind that I have limited experience with Java, especially with GUI oriented Java.

EDIT: If I am not explaining the concept well enough please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do advanced layouts, you should take a look at [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/).

It's an extremely flexible layout manager that can pretty much act as a replacement for any/all of the existing Swing layout managers. It's worth using if you want to do difficult / complex layouts.

It feels more like a HTML table layout tool, enabling multi-column spans etc. and arbitrary scaling rules.

The "[Quick Start Guide](http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf)" is very good with lots of examples - I'd suggest taking a look at that if you want to evaluate MigLayout for your project.

Comment: I don't know much about LayoutManagers but MigLayout seems interesting. Do you have any experience using it? If you do, could you explain why it would be better than using GridBagLayout?

Comment: I've used it in a couple of projects - it has worked very well. Mostly it just gives you more flexibility / options to get the layout you want without having to resort to nesting different kinds of Swing layout managers.

Answer (score 2):

check this out-
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

GridLayout is likely to meet your needs and it is easy to use - the assumption I make is that image of bandwidth graph is the same/fixed ...

Look for an example here 
http://www.roseindia.net/tutorialsearch/?t=java+gridlayout+color

Try Google the keyword "GridLayout" - there are plenty of hits ...

Comment: Thankyou for your input. I'd like to leave this question unanswered overnight and allow anyone else to give any other kind of input. If there is none, I will decided to go ahead and use GridBagLayout and mark your answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the 'bandwidth graph' image(s) is on top of the BG image, look to [OverlayLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/OverlayLayout.html)

> A layout manager to arrange components over the top of each other. ..

OTOH I would not use a layout strategy for this, instead..

1. Create a `BufferedImage` the size of the BG.
2. Paint the BG to the image.
3. Display the image in a label.
4. When it comes time to paint the graphs, get a `Graphics` instance for the image in the label, and paint them to that.  If the graphs are always the same size and shape and do not have transparency, you can simply paint them.  Otherwise, draw the BG first.

Comment: Thank-you for your input. Like I said, I'm pretty new to GUI oriented Java and have been researching the aspects to your suggested plan. Would you have anytime to go over it with a little more explanation 1 on 1 and answer any questions I may have?

Comment: I only do '1 on 1' commercially.  What is your question?

Comment: Well, it's more of just a lack of understanding I suppose. Could you recommend any good tutorials that will help me understand this sort of process?

Comment: Tutorials for which sort?  Using the layout or just using a `BufferedImage`?  Note that at this stage, 'more words is better than less' when you are explaining something.  This is because I have neither the time nor patience to play 20 questions on a Q&A site (that is what '1 on 1 consultancy' is for).

Comment: Relax man, I'm new to the community here, I wasn't aware that there are members here who preferred to charge for certain resources like a 1 on 1. I'm also pretty new to java so I'm likely to not understand all the ins and outs and terminology. I'm just an intern trying not to screw up his first tech related job haha. Let's just forget it though, I think I'm going to look more into MigLayout. Thanks for your time though.